# Plugin [id: 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Plugin [id: 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

'''

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

}
```

'''

Answer (score 8):

It looks like in your root `build.gradle` you're missing a:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}
```

as explained in the instructions here: https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin

Comment: How can we migrate this to the new plugin block?

something like below
id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin.secrets-gradle-plugin") version "2.0.1" apply false

Comment: https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin helped me.

Answer (score 6):

The question is missing some information.
I will suggest following the guide below step by step.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin

The two things that come in to mind at first glance are?

1. Specify the version of the plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1'

}
```

2. Add the following at the top of your settings.gradle or settings.gradle.kts.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = ...
```

Comment: This should be documented on their official documentation.