# Android Studio Flamingo AGP Update issue

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated Android Studio to Flamingo, Im trying to update the AGP as per AS recommendation to 7.4.2.
But its giving this exception:

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin', version: '2.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin.gradle.plugin:2.0.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google
  MavenRepo

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023432/plugin-id-com-google-android-libraries-mapsplatform-secrets-gradle-plugin-w ?